# If $f$ is holomorphic and $\lim_{|z|\to\infty} |f(z)| = 0$ then $f$ is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

> If  $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and  $\lim_{|z|\to\infty} |f(z)| = 0$ then $f$ is polynomial

**My attempt**

I tried to prove that $f^{(k)}(w) = 0$,  $\forall w\in \mathbb{C}$ and for all $k \geq n$ for some $n$.

Given $\varepsilon>0 $ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(z)|<\varepsilon$,  if $|z|\geq \delta$.

For $w\in\mathbb C$ fixed and $r$ such that $C = \{z \in \mathbb{C},|z-w|=R\}\subset\{z\in\mathbb C,|z|\geq \delta\}$, we have from  the Cauchy integral formula
$$f^{(k)}(w) =\frac{k!}{2i\pi}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^{k+1}}dz 
 $$

hence 
$$|f^{(k)}(w)|\leq \frac{k!}{2\pi}\int_C  \frac{|f(z)|}{|z-w|^{k+1}}|dz|\leq 
\frac{\varepsilon k!}{R^{k}}$$

I am stuck here.

I don't know how to find $n$ and if the inequality I've proved helps.

Comment: Do you know Liouville theorem ?

Comment: Why are you stuck?  You can let $\varepsilon$ go to $0$ (and allow $R$ to grow, if necessary) to get $|f^{(k)}(w)|=0$.  Or, you can just let $R$ grow (for a fixed $\varepsilon$).

Comment: @Jennifer, yes I do.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, so the function must be constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\lim_{|z|\to\infty} |f(z)| = 0$, so $\exists R,\forall z \in\mathbb{C}/D(0,R),|f(z)|<1$, also since $f$ is holomorphic it is continuous in $D(0,R)$, so $f$ is bounded in $D(0,R)$ thus $\exists M,\forall z \in D(0,R),|f(z)|<M$. Finally $\forall z \in \mathbb{C},|f(z)|<\max(1,M)$. So with Liouville's theorem $f$ is constant, so $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: And more specifically, $f$ must equal $0$!

Comment: yep :p ${}{}{}$